# How to make this picture no longer sawtooth around?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5hgQ.jpg)

How to make this picture no longer sawtooth around? Without changing the color array.

Comment: Can you put the image inline and add more details?

Comment: You need a lowpass/smoothing/blurring filter, such as a Gaussian.

Comment: Is this the image at the real resolution ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do that by blurring a mask in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Threshold to create a mask
- Blur the mask and stretch so that 127.5 goes to 0 and 255 stays at 255
- Convert the mask to float in range 0 to 1
- Multiply the input by the mask and convert back to 8-bit integer and clip to range 0 to 255
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

# load image
img = cv2.imread('man.jpg')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 16, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# blur threshold image
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (0,0), sigmaX=5, sigmaY=5, borderType = cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)

# stretch so that 255 -> 255 and 127.5 -> 0
mask = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(blur, in_range=(127.5,255), out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.float32) / 255
mask = cv2.merge([mask,mask,mask])

# replace alpha channel in input with new alpha channel
result = (mask * img).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# save output
cv2.imwrite('man_thresh.png', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('man_mask.png', mask)
cv2.imwrite('man_antialiased.png', result)

# Display various images to see the steps
cv2.imshow('gray',gray)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('result', result)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold image:

[image]

Mask image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure that the OP wanted to keep the aliasing on the internal edges and I think he posted an enlarged image.

Comment: Each color could be masked and antialiased and then combined again if desired.